# SSAS update the cube while the underlying data is updating

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

Can the underlying data being used by the SSAS cube be updating while the cube is updating?

We process our cube in full once a week to clean it up (process update and process indexes during the week).  However, there is a demand to process the data in full more than once.  The data warehouse also has daily jobs to update data and our full cube process takes 24 hours.  Currently we stage our daily updates after their jobs and the full cube processing is done in a way to avoid colliding with their data load jobs.  But, if we are to meet the demand of processing the data more than once, we would run into times when the data warehouse is updating.

Does this just cause the cube processing to take longer as it waits for the underlying data changes to stop?  Or, does it grab a snapshot as it goes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The default is just standard read-locks. You can verify this in the Datasource for the cube - It'll probably say "Read Committed" for the isolation level. This means it'll take locks and release them as it reads. If data is modified after the read starts, it may be included in the  cube process if that row hasn't been read yet.

Have you considered either snapshot isolation, or setting the database into Read Committed Snapshot mode? I did the latter with my DW and haven't looked back. I have my cube process incrementally after regular ETL loads, and with RCS I can also do SQL queries against the DW while the ETL is loading (Readers don't block writers).